# Can Multiple BackgroundWorkers use the same Function / end Variable?

Tags: vb.net, thread-safety, backgroundworker

Is that okay if let's say I have

```
BackgroundWoker1
BackgroundWoker2
```

Both of them are having :

```
AddHandler BackgroundWoker1.DoWork, AddressOf requestDataTravelPackagesName
AddHandler BackgroundWoker1.ProgressChanged, AddressOf showLoadingAnim
```

and in the other line (with different time usage)

```
AddHandler BackgroundWoker2.DoWork, AddressOf requestDataTravelPackagesName
AddHandler BackgroundWoker2.ProgressChanged, AddressOf showLoadingAnim
```

Is this allowed? Because I tried the similar thing, and it appeared that my Form malfunctions.
But it doesn't gives me any error / message. the Frame (GUI) just vanished.

I'm thinking perhaps this is because of the multiple background workers that I have. Probably they are accessing the same variable (at the completed function) or in the similar function / etc.

Comment: Actually I would recommend to avoid BackgroundWorkers, as there are better alternatives, like Tasks, Threads, ThreadPools etc.

Comment: @Trade, I couldn't disagree more.  There's no reason at all to avoid BackgroundWorkers.  I can see how you might suggest using a Task instead but to suggest that using the Thread or ThreadPool classes where a BackgroundWorker is appropriate, i.e. performing a background task in a Form or Window, is just poor advice.

Comment: Hm, imo the BackgroundWorker isn't such a good solution. I did not make good experiences with it. Also I miss the exception handling there a bit, because it swallows the exceptions and gets to the RunWorkerCompleted-event etc. That was imo a bit confusing. The advantages are that you can report the progress directly to the UI, but in general I like tasks more, it is just more modern and brings a lot of nice features.

Comment: @Trade, you can handle an exception in the DoWork event handler in exactly the same way as you handle exceptions anywhere else and, for unhandled exceptions, the RunWorkerCompleted event handler provides the e.Error property.  Any issues you had with the BackgroundWorker was as a result of your not using it properly.  If you're building multi-threading directly into forms or windows (which may in itself not be a great idea but that's another issue) then a BackgroundWorker can be an excellent solution.  It's not the best tool for every job but it's better than other tools for some jobs.

Comment: Yes, but needing to call the e.Error-property is a bit confusing, especially for people that are new to BGWs, because you don't understand why there are no exceptions appearing.
If so, you could do it with the BGW, but I would prefer tasks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely no issue with what you're suggesting in principle.  If there's an issue then it's with your implementation.

The DoWork event handler is simply a method that gets executed on a secondary thread.  It's very common to have the same method executing on multiple threads at the same time and there's no issue with that.  The ProgressChanged event handler gets executed on the UI thread so you're never going to have more than one instance executing at a time anyway.

As in all multi-threading scenarios, you always need to ensure that you synchronise access to common data.  All the issues that may arise with single-threaded code must be taken into account too, as well as possible cross-threaded access to controls to avoid.

To know what the issue is in your specific case, we'd need to know EXACTLY what happens in your specific case.

Comment: not a useful comment but couldn't agree with you more. Bravo.